# Pygame diagonal movement not at correct angle

Tags: python, pygame

I would like my player to move diagonally at the same speed as it does when only moving horizontally or vertically. This does work when moving in a line with a negative gradient however, when moving along a positive gradient, the player doesn't move at a perfect 45 degree angle.

This is my code for moving the player:

```
def move(self, speed):
    if self.direction.magnitude() != 0:
        self.direction = self.direction.normalize()
            
    self.rect.x += self.direction.x * speed
    self.rect.y += self.direction.y * speed
```

As I said earlier, all I want is for the player to move diagonally at the same speed as it does in only the x or y direction.

Here is the full player class in case it is needed:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.speed = 5 

    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[K_w]:
            self.direction.y = -1
        elif keys[K_s]:
            self.direction.y = 1
        else:
            self.direction.y = 0
            
        if keys[K_a]:
            self.direction.x = -1
        elif keys[K_d]:
            self.direction.x = 1
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0

    def move(self, speed):
        if self.direction.magnitude() != 0:
            self.direction = self.direction.normalize()
            
        self.rect.x += self.direction.x * speed
        self.rect.y += self.direction.y * speed

    def update(self):
        self.input()
        self.move(self.speed)
            
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.center)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

The fraction part of the coordinates gets lost when the new position of the object is assigned to the *Rect* object. If you want to move the object with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate variables respectively attributes and to synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates and assign it to the location  of the rectangle:

```py
class Player:
   def __init__(self, x, y):
       self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
       self.image.fill((255, 255, 255))
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
       self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2()
       self.speed = 5 

       self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y)

   def input(self):
       keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
       dx = keys[K_d] - keys[K_a]
       dy = keys[K_s] - keys[K_w]
       self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(dx, dy)
       if dx != 0 and dy != 0:
           self.direction /= 1.41421

   def move(self, speed):    
       self.position += self.direction * speed
       self.rect.x = round(self.position.x)
       self.rect.y = round(self.position.y)
       
   def update(self):
       self.input()
       self.move(self.speed)
           
   def draw(self, screen):
       screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.center)
```

See also [Pygame doesn't let me use float for rect.move, but I need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468413/pygame-doesnt-let-me-use-float-for-rect-move-but-i-need-it/63468637#63468637) and [moving with a normalized vector in pygame inconsistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486375/moving-with-a-normalized-vector-in-pygame-inconsistent/68486486#68486486).

---

Note, that [`pygame.math.Vector2.magnitude`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.magnitude) and [`math.Vector2.normalize`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.normalize) are expensive for performance. Try to avoid this operations. Normalization of the vector is only required when moving along both axes. Since the absolute value of the vector is √2 in this case, the normalization can be replaced by dividing by √2.

```py
dx = keys[K_d] - keys[K_a]                   # dx is -1, 0 or 1
dy = keys[K_s] - keys[K_w]                   # dy is -1, 0 or 1
self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(dx, dy)
if dx != 0 and dy != 0:  
    self.direction /= 1.41421                # sqrt(2) is ~1.41421
```